# Prove or disprove If f is continuous and g is dicontinuous then f + g is discontinuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, function $f\colon A\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous at $a\in A$, and $g\colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous at $a\in A$.
>   Prove or disprove that $f+g$ is discontinuous at $a\in A$.

A proof by definition is what I need. But if ones try with the other way that's okay.
Help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. what did you try?

Comment: Do you know the theorem that the sum of two  continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: @Potato Yes, I do. But my bad when I was on my exam I didn't even notice that theorem.

Comment: @DanisFischer I wrote out the def of continuous f and discontunious g. I supposed that f+g continuous then found a contradiction. My lecturer gave me score 6 of 10 for this problem. I know there were some "prompted" steps in my answer. lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may already know that the sum and the difference of two continuous functions are continuos.
Let $f$ be continuous, $g$ not continuous and let $h=f+g$. If we assume tha t$h$ is continuous, then by what I just mentioned, $g= h-f$ is also continuous, contradiction. Hence $h$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: Ahhh It's so clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=x, g = \frac{1}{x}$, then $f$ continous at $0$, but $g$ isn't. And $f+g = x+\frac{1}{x}$ which is still not continous at $0$.

[image]

Comment: This is a relevant example, but not a proof.

Comment: But your $g$ is continuous in its domain of definition!

Comment: @mathmandan: I'm just showing an example so maybe the OP can figure it out on his/her own.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:@Hagen von Eitzen, I am not sure what you are saying. Yeah it's continuous outside of $0$, so? This was just to serve as an example so the OP could try and figure it out.